# The visual studio application and corresponding process in the list of Windows Task Manager

Tags: visual-studio

I am using the Remoting. I open 2 visual stuido, and I find 2 devenv.exe processes in Windows Task Manager. I know these are for the 2 visual studio. But I also find other processes like Client.vshost.exe What are they processes for? Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *.vshost.exe:
Open the project's property setting, at the tab[Debug], uncheck the [Visual Studio Host Process](like this). Because I'm using not english version VS, so I can't write complete the check item's label.

Comment: Do you know what is this vshost.exe for?